# VS code How to place open braces on the same line?

Tags: visual-studio-code

Visual Studio code puts braces on new line(C# style). Functions look something like this.

```
public string GetString()
        {
            string hi = "Hello World";
            return hi;
        }
```

I want to put braces immediately after function name. like this:

```
public string GetString(){
            string hi = "Hello World";
            return hi;
        }
```

I checked all the settings and did not find any ways to solve this issue. I will be glad if anyone could help me.

Comment: Looks like this is possible with Omnisharp: https://github.com/OmniSharp/omnisharp-vscode/issues/243

Answer (score 0):

For JavaScript and Typescript, VSCode supports the following settings.

`"typescript.format.placeOpenBraceOnNewLineForFunctions": boolean
"typescript.format.placeOpenBraceOnNewLineForControlBlocks": boolean
"javascript.format.placeOpenBraceOnNewLineForFunctions": boolean
"javascript.format.placeOpenBraceOnNewLineForControlBlocks": boolean`

Reference: [JavaScript in VS Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/javascript)